# Merging two Pandas DataFrames on specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas dataframes, and I want to merge them on specific condition. These are my dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 250)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 7)
pd.set_option('display.width', 800)


df1 = pd.DataFrame({"food":["fruit", "fruit", "fruit"],
                    "name":["apple", "grape", "bannana"]})
print(df1)


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"name":["apple", "apple", "apple", "grape", "grape"],
                    "color":["red", "green", "yellow","white", "blue"]})
print(df2)
```

They look like this:

```
    food     name
0  fruit    apple
1  fruit    grape
2  fruit  bannana

    name   color
0  apple     red
1  apple   green
2  apple  yellow
3  grape   white
4  grape    blue
```

I want from my result dataframe to look like this:

```
    food   name   color
0  fruit  apple     red
1  fruit  apple   green
2  fruit  apple  yellow
3  fruit  grape   white
4  fruit  grape    blue
```

So I want to merge them on "name" column but I want to drop nan values. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe share an example with NaNs too so its easier to see what you mean

Comment: I do not have nans in my two dataframes, I guess that NaN will appear after merging because I do not have all values ( "Bannana value" )

Comment: you can use merge or concat and then dropna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.merge` to join the dataframes, and the use `.dropna` to drop the rows with NA values.

```py
df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='name').dropna()
# returns:
    food   name   color
0  fruit  apple     red
1  fruit  apple   green
2  fruit  apple  yellow
3  fruit  grape   white
4  fruit  grape    blue
```